# why uwsgi workers idle but nginx showed a lot of timeouts?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

Stack: nginx, uwsgi, django

uwsgitop and top both showed uwsgi workers are idle, while nginx error log said upstream timed out.

I thought  some of request needed a lot of resources such as waiting for db or cache, while the others not.  After checking the timed out requests, most of them were not voracious. Any kind of request had been timed out.

So why nginx didn't seed the requests to idle ones if the others were really busy? why uwsgi master just keep someone busy and the others idle?

Comment: in my experience nginx wsgi implementation performs poorly, specially if the application tend to block for a few miliseconds.

Comment: Are they doing this all the time or only when the load is high? Do you have a lot of IO in your site?

Comment: @PauloScardine uwsgi actually worked very well in both sync or async way, though I dare not use async mode. I use celery instead.  I thought uwsig was blocking as well, but the other workers are idle, so it couldn't be blocking issue.

Comment: @RickyA yes, load and IO had been the problem, but we then resolved these problems. Previously, DB IO was very high, after some tune, I removed high IO.

Comment: @PauloScardine i suppose you are talking about mod_wsgi for nginx, a completely different project (now with a different name too), because uWSGI does not run in nginx process address space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd like to answer my own question.

change the kernel parameter: net.ipv4.ip_conntrack_max  from 65560 to 6556000

I have a full story on how we found the answer:

1. user said slow, slow, slow
2. nginx flooded with  "upstream connection timed out"
3. I checked uwsgi log, found some of errors, fixed it; found more, fix more, and this loop lasted days. Till yesterday, I thought there was no relevance with uwsgi, memcached, db, redis, or anything backend because uwsgi were idle
4. so I thought  nginx must have had something wrong, reload, restart, check connections, workers, proxy_read_timeout, etc. no luck.
5. checked ulimit -n, which reported 1024, the default one. I have 8 nginx workers, so connections should reach to 1024 * 8, I thought that could be ok as nginx never said too many open files. Anyway, I changed it to 4096. NO luck.
6. check connections number, and the state, then problem appears. upstream connections were  all in syn_sent state, then timeout happends. Only 2 or 3 of 300 connections are in established state. We wanted to know why. One of my friends told my part to use tcpdump, the magic tool I never dare to try once.
7. Then we  go to syslog and found the following error, and finally we resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my listen queue was growing and the RPS was low despite all the workers idling.

samuel found one of the cases but there are a few more potential causes for this behavior:

- net.core.somaxconn not high enough
- uwsgi `--listen` not high enough
- nginx worker processes too low
- nginx worker connections too low

If none of these work, then you'll want to check your logs that inbound requests to uWSGI are under http/1.1 and not http/1.0, and then use `--http11-socket`

Here are some of my findings when I wrestled with this issue: https://wontonst.blogspot.com/2019/06/squishing-performance-bug-in.html

The nginx tuning page also has some other configurations that may or may not be useful in solving this issue:
https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/